# Apache Mina: IllegalStateException when calling connect

Tags: android, apache-mina

I am trying to make a simple message application on Android with Apache Mina. I am getting `IllegalStateException` when calling `connect(new InetSocketAddress(HOSTNAME, PORT))`.

Here is my client code:
http://pastebin.com/NR2H6X0t

Here is my server code:
http://pastebin.com/Q5fQnu2p

And here is the logcat output:

http://pastebin.com/Egsh0Ce4

I am testing my apllications in same wifi network with a tablet and phone.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code. Are you sure your port is available and your server is listening there? (although this shouldn't be a problem, but just checking)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even I can't see anything wrong with your code. But the LogCat says `org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketConnector.connect()` of `NioSocketConnector.java` class at line# 185) your application is throwing `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. First fix that than check if you are getting the same error.

Apart from above I have a suggestion (for readability purpose): In `connectToServerButtonClicked()` of ClientActivity instead of using

```
for (; ; ) { 
    //rest of your code 
}
```

better use

```
while(true){
    //rest of your code
}
```

Edited: On request of @alkis coping my answer from comment below to answer part for better redability

`NetworkOnMainThreadException` : This exception is **thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread**. Run your network related code in AsyncTask.

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException : This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. Run your network related code in AsyncTask.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. I will try it.

Comment: Please put your comment in your answer. As it seems that's the solution, so it should be visible. Great answer, it will save a lot of people from future frustration.